# Bridge/route a wireless connection

Tags: networking, wireless, network-bridge

I was trying to follow this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EasyWirelessToWiredConnectionSharing but it does'nt seem to be upgraded. The dhcpd.conf file is in `/etc/dhcp` and not in `/etc/dhcp3`. But a worse problem is that I can't find `/etc/default/dhcp3-server` at all. How would I do this in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are logged in:

- Go to Network menu in the panel.
- Navigate to "Edit connections".
- When that window opens, select "Auto eth0", and press "Edit" (This assumes that you are connected to the Internet on some other port, for example wlan0 using wireless).
- A new window will open. Navigate to the tab titled "IPv4 Settings", and change the Method to "Shared to other computers".

After restarting the computer, you should now be able to plug in any computer into your other Ethernet port or share through your wireless card.

Comment: Oh, that seemed alot simplier than what I tried. Unfortunatly I could'nt get it to work. But I should try a little more and get back...

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with /etc/network/interface ? \

Anyway, I had the same problem, however on 12.04.
I tried edm's fix but it didn't help. Then I tried changing the method to "only local" for eth0 and then changing the method for wlan0 to "shared to other computers".

Then by using "ifconfig" in terminal I found that eth0 had changed IP to 10.42.0.1, so I used that IP as gateway on my other device (in my case a Raspberry Pi) and took 10.42.0.2 as IP on my device. It works for me now; I didn't really need the dhcp server anyway.

Comment: Very interesting. I really never got it working and gave up. My question was also regarding a Raspberry Pi. So now I will try again...